# Problem with Text,becoming blur While transforming UITextView in iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

Hello
I am working an application where i need to transform a UIView on which one UITextView is added for zooming effect.After animating the UIView with "CGAffineTransformMakeScale" the view size is getting bigger as desired but the text in side the UITextView is becoming blur.can any one suggest me a way to over come this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text view is being scaled as pixels. It's like zooming in on an image in photoshop: the pixels are enlarged so it doesn't get any sharper. I would recommend making the view's frame larger, and at the same time increasing the font size. Not sure if you can animate them together smoothly, but the end result should be what you want. Perhaps as you scale it up (as you're doing now) you can cross-fade it with a larger-text version that starts scaled down.